# Angular JS - bootstrap modal ENTER key press with two buttons, only one is visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal screen that lets the user create new publications and edit existing ones:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <form role="form">
    <div class="modal-header ng-scope">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{ items.ui.header }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body ng-scope">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <input type="hidden" name="publicationId" ng-model="items.publication.id" />
                <label for="publicationTitle">{{ items.ui.label }}</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="publicationTitle" name="publicationTitle" ng-model="items.publication.title"  />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer ng-scope">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="new()" ng-show="items.ui.modalType=='new'" ng-enter="new();">{{ items.ui.action }}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="edit()" ng-show="items.ui.modalType=='edit'"ng-enter="edit();">{{ items.ui.action }}</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger pull-left" ng-click="delete()" ng-show="items.ui.modalType=='edit'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Where at any given time, only one the two buttons `new()` and `edit()` are shown. However, when I use the `ENTER` key to submit the form, it sometimes triggers the wrong action. In fact, it triggers the previous action in the modal, even though the button is not shown.
What better way is there of achieving this?

Comment: You can use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`: in this case Angular will not create DOM element if expression is false.

Comment: Consider using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is that ng-show and ng-hide sets the display to none. Means that the element is still present on the DOM.

In order to solve that, you can use ng-if instead, which will delete the element from the DOM or will recreate it.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf